# MobileFirst Error handling "unexpected response"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to change the behaviour of my application if my server is unreachable where it shows the following error:

[image]

I have been doing some R&D on my application including if I can control this from `challengeHandler` which even if I added a custom behaviour to my `challengeHandler` , the above message appears with my custom one.

```
bankingLoginChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
        if (!response || !response.responseJSON
                                    || response.responseText === null) {
                                alert("Connection Failed");}
```

I noticed that the only way to control the above dialog is from my initOption.js as the following:

```
onSuccess : function (response) {
        alert (response); // result is always undefined no matter the server status
        if (!response || !response.responseJSON
            || response.responseText === null){
            WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                    "Server Error",
                    "Server is unavailable , Please contact our support",
                    [{text: "Close", handler: null}]
            );
        }
```

And I see the behaviour changed, and the following dialog replace the one above:

[image]

The problem is that the response always comes as "undefined" no matter what is the server status is (Up or Down), (I have Added `alert(response)`to my initOption onSuccess to see what it is if the server is up and down) and because of that my condition is always true and the dialog appears.

I'm confused on how can I manage this error message.

Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this?

Comment: No I haven't. I tried all options I have. I don't know what is the condition of "response" that is shown onSuccess that I need to use to present the server unavailable message.